# Navigate to specific tab on the Account Object

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate, forcenavigatetourl

Hi I have created a tab name  "Test Client" on the Account Object, beside the previously present Details tab. So there are two tabs on the flexipage of the Account Object == "Details" and new made by me "Test Client".

As per the req i need my user on  the click of the button should get navigated to the particular record on the Account page but instead of Detail page it should be directed on the "Test Client".

below is the code i tried, it is helping me to navigate to the detail  tab page ,,,but not on the test client page kindly some one help me out

```
navigaToTestclienTabOnAccount(evt) {
        
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__navItemPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.acccountId,
                objectApiName: 'Account',
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
    }
```

Kindly someone help me out...this one is for LWC. i am not using Aura

Answer (score 3):

You can't navigate to a particular tab on a record page in Lightning. This is not yet supported in Lightning.

However, if your requirement is that user should always navigate to a particular tab whenever Account(or other objects) is opened from whatever source(list view, global search, link, custom Aura/LWC component), you can make the tab as the 'default' one by editing the record page.

If its not the requirement then I am afraid you will not be able to achieve it.

Comment: This is soo bad :(

Comment: Is there a solution for this now?

Comment: No solution yet